# WPF DataTemplate, TemplateSelectors, ContentPresenter based on SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, contentpresenter, datatemplateselector

I am very confused what to use and how to start implementations, but I want is based on a Enum property when changed a certain grid should display.

Currently I have like 20 grids, working with visibility when the property change.
This is not ideal for 2 things. All 20 grids will bind from startup and it isnot good for performance. Secondly some "Grids" are the same for some values of the enum property. So I have duplicate code in some grids.

Now what I have is an enum:

```
   public enum MyEnumsForDropDown
    {
        Enum1= 1,
        Enum2= 2,
        Enum3= 3,
        Enum4= 4,
        Enum5= 5
    }
```

My Object in my ViewModel, which I bind to is for :

```
Public class MyObject
{
  private Enums.MyEnumsForDropDown _myChosenEnum;
  public Enums.MyEnumsForDropDown MyChosenEnum
  {
    get { return _myChosenEnum; }
    set
    {
      _myChosenEnum = value;
      this.NotifyPropertyChanged( x => x.MyChosenEnum );
    }
  }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfEnums}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding 
MyObject.MyChosenEnum}"></ComboBox>

<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Visibility="{Binding 
Path=MyObject.MyChoseEnum, Converter={StaticResource 
EnumToVisibleCollapseConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static 
myenumsNameSpace:Enums+MyEnumsForDropDown.Enum1}}">
  <TextBlock Content"This Grid displays when Enum1 is chosen"/>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Visibility="{Binding 
Path=MyObject.MyChoseEnum, Converter={StaticResource 
EnumToVisibleCollapseConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static 
myenumsNameSpace:Enums+MyEnumsForDropDown.Enum2}}">
  <TextBlock Content"This Grid displays when Enum2 is chosen"/>
</Grid>
```

How do I change the Grids to work somehow like ContentPresenters or DataTemplates or whatever I need to use depended on when the property MyChosenEnum changes in my object??

Comment: The disadvantage of such approach is that all grids are in visual tree (disregards of visibility), participating in binding and eating some performance. You could instead change control template of single element using data triggers. There are multi data triggers for complicated cases. See [tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/multi-triggers-multitrigger-multidatatrigger/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a `DataTemplate` for each enum value and then use a `ContentControl` with a `Style` to display the correct one:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyObject.MyChosenEnum}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Enum1">
            <Grid />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Enum2">
            <Grid />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyObject.MyChosenEnum}"
                             Value="{x:Static myenumsNameSpace:Enums+MyEnumsForDropDown.Enum1}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Enum1}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyObject.MyChosenEnum}"
                             Value="{x:Static myenumsNameSpace:Enums+MyEnumsForDropDown.Enum2}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Enum2}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <!-- and so on for each enum value -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Or you could use a `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
public class YourSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Enum1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Enum2 { get; set; }
    //...

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        MyEnumsForDropDown value = (MyEnumsForDropDown)item;
        switch(value)
        {
            case MyEnumsForDropDown.Enum1:
                return Enum1;
            case MyEnumsForDropDown.Enum2:
                return Enum2;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

---

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Enum1">
            <Grid />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Enum2">
            <Grid />
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:YourSelector x:Key="selector" Enum1="{StaticResource Enum1}" Enum2="{StaticResource Enum2}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyObject.MyChosenEnum}"
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I went for the second option

Comment: I am loosing my ViewModel inside the DataTemplate, is possible to keep the same ViewModel for the two different templates??